# AdminTokenAction: FATAL ERROR: Cannot obtain Application SSO token

Tags: java, single-sign-on, openam

I was trying to install openam 12 war with apache tomcat agent as configured sso.But tried more than fifty times but am getting only error.

If I change below property value as *amAdmin* from *webagent*,while calling the protected application in tomcat second instance it countinously redirecting to same page again and again but didn't get any exception. amAdmin is my admin user of openam console.

```
OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties/com.sun.identity.agents.app.username =
```

**Exception in Tomcat log**

```
Apr 16, 2015 5:41:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.bootStrapClientConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:727)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.initializeConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:1140)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.<clinit>(AgentConfiguration.java:1579)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.Manager.<clinit>(Manager.java:675)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.<clinit>(AmTomcatRealm.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: com.sun.identity.security.AMSecurityPropertiesException: AdminTokenAction:  FATAL ERROR: Cannot obtain Application SSO token.
Check AMConfig.properties for the following properties
    com.sun.identity.agents.app.username
    com.iplanet.am.service.password
    at com.sun.identity.security.AdminTokenAction.run(AdminTokenAction.java:272)
    at com.sun.identity.security.AdminTokenAction.run(AdminTokenAction.java:76)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.identity.common.configuration.ConfigurationObserver.registerListeners(ConfigurationObserver.java:89)
    at com.sun.identity.common.configuration.ConfigurationObserver.getInstance(ConfigurationObserver.java:114)
    at com.sun.identity.common.DebugPropertiesObserver.<clinit>(DebugPropertiesObserver.java:49)
    ... 32 more
```

**host entry**

```
127.0.0.1 org.sso.com test.openam.com
```

**Tomcat two instances from apache-tomcat-7.0.57**

```
**1, One for OpenAM.12.0.war running in port 8080
2, Another one for webagent(openam-Tomcat-v6-7-Agent-3.3.0.zip) with my protected application running in port 7070**
```

**OpenAM configuration :**

```
1, Default configuration amAdmin with password (password) and policy-agent with password(password1) created.
2, Login as amAdmin -->Access Control -- >OpenAMIDPRealm-->created
3, Access Control -- >OpenAMIDPRealm-->subject-->idpuser-->password(password)-->created
4, Access Control -- >OpenAMIDPRealm-->agent-->J2EE-->name(webagent)-->password(password)-->local-->agenturl(http://org.sso.com:7070/agentapp)-->created
5, Federation -- >Create Circle of Trust -- > OpenAMIDPCOT -->select realm (OpenAMIDPRealm) -->created
6, Common Tasks --> create hosted identity provider --> select realm (OpenAMIDPRealm) -->  select Circle of Trust -- > OpenAMIDPCOT -->created
```

**Web Agent configuration :**

```
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\webagent\j2ee_agents\tomcat_v6_agent\bin>agentadmin --install

Please read the following License Agreement carefully:

[Press <Enter> to continue...] or [Enter n To Finish]


************************************************************************
Welcome to the OpenAM Policy Agent for Apache Tomcat 6.0 Servlet/JSP
Container

************************************************************************


Enter the complete path to the directory which is used by Tomcat Server to
store its configuration Files. This directory uniquely identifies the
Tomcat Server instance that is secured by this Agent.
[ ? : Help, ! : Exit ]
Enter the Tomcat Server Config Directory Path [C:/Program Files/Apache
Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/conf]: D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat
-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf


Enter the URL where the OpenAM server is running. Please include the
deployment URI also as shown below:
(http://openam.sample.com:58080/openam)
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
OpenAM server URL: http://test.openam.com:8080/openam


$CATALINA_HOME environment variable is the root of the tomcat
installation.
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
Enter the $CATALINA_HOME environment variable: D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apac
he-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57


Choose yes to deploy the policy agent in the global web.xml file.
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
Install agent filter in global web.xml ? [true]: true


Enter the Agent URL. Please include the deployment URI also as shown below:
(http://agent1.sample.com:1234/agentapp)
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
Agent URL: http://org.sso.com:7070/agentapp


Enter the Agent profile name
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
Enter the Agent Profile name: webagent


Enter the path to a file that contains the password to be used for identifying
the Agent.
[ ? : Help, < : Back, ! : Exit ]
Enter the path to the password file: D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\password.txt


WARNING:
Agent profile/User: webagent does not exist in OpenAM server! Either "Hit
the Back button, and re-enter the correct agent profile name/user name", or
"Create this agent profile when asked(available only in custom-install)",
or "Continue without validating it because agent profile is in sub realm", or
"Continue without validating/creating it, and manually validate/create
it in OpenAM server after installation".



-----------------------------------------------
SUMMARY OF YOUR RESPONSES
-----------------------------------------------
Tomcat Server Config Directory :
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf

OpenAM server URL : http://test.openam.com:8080/openam
$CATALINA_HOME environment variable :
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57

Tomcat global web.xml filter install : true
Agent URL : http://org.sso.com:7070/agentapp
Agent Profile name : webagent
Agent Profile Password file name :
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\password.txt

Verify your settings above and decide from the choices below.
1. Continue with Installation
2. Back to the last interaction
3. Start Over
4. Exit
Please make your selection [1]: 1

Updating the
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/setenv.ba
t
script with the Agent configuration JVM option ...DONE.
DONE.

Creating directory layout and configuring Agent file for Agent_001
instance ...DONE.

Reading data from file D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\password.txt and
encrypting it ...DONE.

Generating audit log file name ...DONE.

Creating tag swapped OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties file for instance
Agent_001 ...DONE.

Creating a backup for file
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf/server.x
ml
...DONE.

Creating a backup for file
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf/web.xml
...DONE.

Adding OpenAM Tomcat Agent Realm to Server XML file :
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf/server.x
ml
...DONE.

Adding filter to Global deployment descriptor file :
D:\Studies\sso\OpenAM-SP2IDP\apache-tomcat-SP\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf/web.xml
...DONE.

Adding OpenAM Tomcat Agent Filter and Form login authentication to selected
Web applications ...DONE.


SUMMARY OF AGENT INSTALLATION
-----------------------------
Agent instance name: Agent_001
Agent Bootstrap file location:
D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/conf
ig/OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties
Agent Configuration file location
D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/conf
ig/OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties
Agent Audit directory location:
D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/logs
/audit
Agent Debug directory location:
D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/logs
/debug


Install log file location:
D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/installer-logs
/audit/install.log

Thank you for using OpenAM Policy Agent
```

**OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties**

```
com.iplanet.am.naming.url=http://test.openam.com:8080/openam/namingservice
com.sun.identity.agents.config.service.resolver = com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatAgentServiceResolver
com.sun.identity.agents.app.username = webagent
com.iplanet.am.service.secret = AQIC91zdxfnLewLIWRJDohP4vdRaQ/7vpmBl
am.encryption.pwd = lZco703977UeM52+kT4ZdyIjLM2PMw3d
com.iplanet.services.debug.level=error
com.iplanet.services.debug.directory=D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/logs/debug
com.sun.services.debug.mergeall=on
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.logfile = D:/Studies/sso/OpenAM-SP2IDP/webagent/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/Agent_001/logs/audit/amAgent_org_sso_com_7070.log
com.sun.identity.agents.config.organization.name = /
com.sun.identity.agents.config.lock.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profilename = webagent
com.iplanet.am.services.deploymentDescriptor=/openam
```

**openam/WEB-INF/classes/AMConfig.properties**

```
com.iplanet.am.server.host=@SERVER_HOST@
com.iplanet.security.SSLSocketFactoryImpl=com.sun.identity.shared.ldap.factory.JSSESocketFactory
com.sun.identity.sm.sms_object_class_name=com.sun.identity.sm.@SMS_OBJECT_CLASS@
com.iplanet.services.configpath=@BASE_DIR@
com.iplanet.am.serverMode=true
com.iplanet.am.ldap.connection.ldap.error.codes.retries=80,81,91
com.iplanet.am.locale=@PLATFORM_LOCALE@
com.sun.identity.urlconnection.useCache=false
opensso.protocol.handler.pkgs=
com.iplanet.am.server.protocol=@SERVER_PROTO@
com.iplanet.am.server.port=@SERVER_PORT@
com.iplanet.services.debug.level=error
com.sun.embedded.replicationport=
com.sun.identity.common.systemtimerpool.size=3
com.sun.identity.overrideAMC=true
com.sun.embedded.sync.servers=on
com.iplanet.am.service.secret=@ENCLDAPUSERPASSWD@
am.encryption.pwd=@AM_ENC_KEY@
com.sun.identity.sm.enableDataStoreNotification=@DATASTORE_NOTIFICATION@
com.sun.services.debug.mergeall=off
com.iplanet.am.services.deploymentDescriptor=/@SERVER_URI@
com.sun.am.event.connection.disable.list=@DISABLE_PERSISTENT_SEARCH@
```

**Agent_001/conf/OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties**

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.filter.mode[manager]=J2EE_POLICY
com.sun.identity.agents.config.filter.mode[host-manager]=J2EE_POLICY
com.sun.identity.agents.config.filter.mode = ALL
com.sun.identity.agents.config.user.mapping.mode = USER_ID
com.sun.identity.agents.config.user.attribute.name = employeenumber
com.sun.identity.agents.config.user.principal = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.user.token = UserToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.ip.header =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.hostname.header =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.load.interval = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.locale.language = en
com.sun.identity.agents.config.locale.country = US
com.sun.identity.agents.config.audit.accesstype = LOG_NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.log.disposition = REMOTE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.logfile = amAgent_org_sso_com_7070.log
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.rotate = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.size = 52428800
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.endpoint[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.process.get.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.authenticator =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.internalerror.content = WSInternalErrorContent.txt
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.autherror.content  = WSAuthErrorContent.txt
com.sun.identity.agents.config.webservice.responseprocessor =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.access.denied.uri[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.form[0] = /host-manager/AMLogin.html
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.form[1] = /manager/AMLogin.html
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.error.uri[0] = /host-manager/AMError.html
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.error.uri[1] = /manager/AMError.html
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.use.internal = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.content.file = FormLoginContent.txt
com.sun.identity.agents.config.auth.handler[] =     
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.handler[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.verification.handler[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.httpsession.binding = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.param = goto
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0] = http://test.openam.com:8080/openam/UI/Login
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url[0] = http://test.openam.com:8080/openam/UI/Logout
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url.prioritized = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url.probe.enabled = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url.probe.timeout = 2000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url.prioritized = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url.probe.enabled = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url.probe.timeout = 2000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.host = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.port =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.protocol =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.attempt.limit = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.amsso.cache.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.name[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.domain[] =  
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.path[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.redirect.uri = /agentapp/sunwCDSSORedirectURI
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0] = http://test.openam.com:8080/openam/cdcservlet
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.clock.skew = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.trusted.id.provider[0] = http://test.openam.com:8080/openam/cdcservlet
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.secure.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.application.handler[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.uri[] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.request.param[] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.introspect.enabled = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.entry.uri[] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.check.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.default = org.sso.com
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.mapping[] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.legacy.support.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.legacy.user.agent[0] = Mozilla/4.7*
com.sun.identity.agents.config.legacy.redirect.uri = /agentapp/sunwLegacySupportURI
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.header[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.attempt.limit = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.port.check.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.port.check.file = PortCheckContent.txt
com.sun.identity.agents.config.port.check.setting[7070] = http
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[0] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri.invert = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri.cache.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri.cache.size = 1000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.refresh.session.idletime = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip[0] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip.invert = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip.cache.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip.cache.size = 1000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.cookie.separator = |
com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.date.format = EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z
com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.cookie.encode = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.fetch.mode = NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.mapping[] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.fetch.mode = NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.mapping[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.fetch.mode = NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.mapping[] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.bypass.principal[0] =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.default.privileged.attribute[0] = AUTHENTICATED_USERS
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.type[0] = Group
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.type[1] = Role
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.tolowercase[Group] = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.tolowercase[Role] = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.session.attribute[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.mapping.enable = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.privileged.attribute.mapping[] =
com.iplanet.am.cookie.name=iPlanetDirectoryPro
com.iplanet.am.session.client.polling.enable=false
com.iplanet.am.session.client.polling.period=180
com.iplanet.security.encryptor=com.iplanet.services.util.JCEEncryption
com.sun.identity.idm.remote.notification.enabled=true
com.iplanet.am.sdk.remote.pollingTime=1
com.sun.identity.sm.notification.enabled=true
com.sun.identity.sm.cacheTime=1
com.iplanet.am.server.protocol=http
com.iplanet.am.server.host=test.openam.com
com.iplanet.am.server.port=8080
com.sun.identity.agents.notification.enabled=true
com.sun.identity.agents.polling.interval=3
com.sun.identity.policy.client.cacheMode=subtree
com.sun.identity.policy.client.booleanActionValues=iPlanetAMWebAgentService|GET|allow|deny:iPlanetAMWebAgentService|POST|allow|deny
com.sun.identity.policy.client.resourceComparators=serviceType=iPlanetAMWebAgentService|class=com.sun.identity.policy.plugins.HttpURLResourceName|wildcard=*|delimiter=/|caseSensitive=false
com.sun.identity.policy.client.clockSkew=10
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.env.get.param[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.env.post.param[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.env.jsession.param[0]=
com.sun.identity.client.notification.url=http://org.sso.com:7070/agentapp/notification
com.iplanet.services.debug.level=error
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info = false
```

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This covers some of the possible root causes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932748/openam-j2ee-agent-installation-bringing-down-tomcat/28944918#28944918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar issue in the past where after the user logs in using the OpenAM login it sits redirecting to itself.

The problem was the cookie domain. When OpenAM authenticates it will set a cookie withe the session token. If tomcat is on a separate domain then it won't be able to look up the cookie.

You might want to check your domain in OpenAM console -> configuration -> system -> platform

My app was Drupal but I think the tomcat config is:

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/something" sessionCookieDomain=".domain.tld" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem could be making use of `com.iplanet.am.naming.map.site.to.server`
This tutorial should cover stuff for you :) 
https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/admin-guide

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree! :) my bad, thank you for your suggestion. Do up vote if you think it solves the problem though. :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue I have observed with these kind of errors is, Open AM 13 might not be compatible with Tomcat-8.5.12. Please change tomcat installation in which open AM is deployed to Tomcat-7.0.69. This has solved my problem.